# Displaying entire year in C# WinForm application

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to display the entire year (not month by month) in MonthCalendar control. If not is there another option or do I have to make my own control. I need to graphically display some events that happen on certain dates or in certain intervals, and I need to display them for entire year so the standard MonthCalendar's display is not applicable in this case.

Comment: how would you want it to look? Not sure if I follow as a year is made up of months, not years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can display a maximum of 12 months. Sincerly I've not worked a lot with this control but looking in the msdn in [MonthCalendar Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar_members%28v=vs.71%29) I found the [MonthCalendar.SetCalendarDimensions Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.setcalendardimensions%28v=vs.71%29) that:

> Sets the number of columns and rows of months to display.

So you need to do this:

```
myMonthCalendarControl.SetCalendarDimensions(4, 3); 
//I used 4 columns and 3 rows because the product should be not greater than 12
```

Comment: Works nicely.  Hadn't see that before.